# Move from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 on a MacBook Pro running OS 10.8.5. I've built an iPhone app (my first) using the iOS 7 SDK. Things are very stable, and the app is, I believe, ready for TestFlight.

Now I'm assailed by Xcode 6 and iOS 8. I want to go forward, but am kind of spooked that switching Xcode at this point may run the risk of breaking things. A lot of the reviews I read are negative, but I expect people who have problems are more likely to bellyache than those for whom things go smoothly. OTOH, I read that TestFlight is well-integrated into Xcode 6.

I recognize that answers to this question may be opinion-based, but I haven't found anything specific offering guidance for my particular circumstance.

Should I take the chance and upgrade Xcode and the app, or wait until I've launched, then upgrade and work iOS 8 support into an update?

**Afterthought**

I just checked and the upgrade to Xcode 6 requires an OSX upgrade to 10.9.3, which adds another layer of terror. :-O

**Resolution**

Ok, I steeled myself and went forward with the upgrade--Mavericks and Xcode 6. First thing I noticed is that my keyboard isn't appearing in my user input modals. But that's a subject for another post. Other than that, the OS and Xcode seem to be working ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! There will be a few adjustments to make, but there always is. The only thing that's caused me extra time so far is Xcode 6 Auto-Layout for iOS 7 devices (e.g. layout margins). But it's not too bad.

Chances are many of your users are already on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus and/or iOS 8. Do you really want to ship to them without optimizing for their devices?

Comment: Excellent point, @Kyle! No, I'll need all the customers I can get!